# Find out if a tuple is contained into another one with repetitions in Python

Tags: python, list, set, tuples

```
Tuple1 = (1,2,2)
TupleList = [(1,2,3), (1,2,3,2)]
```

I want to search in **TupleList** for any tuple being a superset of **Tuple1**. The result should be in this case:

```
(1,2,3,2)
```

But if I use the .issuperset() function, it will not take into account the repetition of the 2 inside **Tuple1**.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: `Tuple1` is not in tuple `(1,2,3)`, as a tuple. As a set, yes. Which one do you want? Also: do you want the biggest superset only?

Comment: But as a set, (1,2,2) will be considered as (1,2). I want to find the tuple in TupleList containing ALL elements of Tuple1 (including repetitions).

Comment: Do you need the elements to appear in order?

Comment: `issuperset` operates on set, IMO you have to write logic to count frequencies and based on that you can get your required list

Comment: Elements do not need to appear in order, they just have to be there (according to the number of times given in the Tuple1)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to consider element frequency this is probably a good use of the `collections.Counter` utility.

```
from collections import Counter


tuple_1 = (1, 2, 2)
tuple_list = [(1, 2, 3), (3, 4, 1), (1, 2, 3, 2)]


def find_superset(source, targets):
    source_counter = Counter(source)
    for target in targets:
        target_counter = Counter(target)
        if is_superset(source_counter, target_counter):
            return target

    return None  # no superset found


def is_superset(source_counter, target_counter):
    for key in source_counter:
        if not target_counter[key] >= source_counter[key]:
            return False
    return True


print(find_superset(tuple_1, tuple_list))
```

Output:

```
(1, 2, 3, 2)
```

Comment: Good, but it gives the first superset only. Yield it instead

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import Counter

def contains(container, contained):
  " True if all values in dictionary container >= values in contained"
  return all(container[x] >= contained[x] for x in contained)

def sublist(lst1, lst2):
  " Detects if all elements in lst1 are in lst2 with at least as many count "
  return contains(Counter(lst1), Counter(lst2), )

Tuple1 = (1,2,2)
TupleList = [(1,2,3), (1,2,3,2)]

# List of tuples from TupleList that contains Tuple1
result = [x for x in TupleList if sublist(x, Tuple1)]

print(result)

>>>[(1, 2, 3, 2)]
```